# Global / local extremums on open intervals

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions

I am not sure if I understand exactly what a local or global maximum / minimum is.

That's why the following question:

Let $f$ be a function defined on the **open** interval $(-1, 1)$ with: $f : (-1, 1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $f(x) = x^3$

Does $f$ has a global or local maximum at $x = 1$? Can it be an extremum at all even though the function itself is not defined at $x$?

Comment: `Does f has a global or local maximum at x=1 ?` Neither, since $f$ is not even defined at $1$.

Comment: @dxiv Does it have a global or local maximum at all?

Comment: No. The function $f(x)=x^3$ is strictly increasing on $\mathbb{R}$, so it has neither global nor local extrema on any open interval.